# Calling CLR Stored Procedure out of Context

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, clr, sqlclr

This is my external procedure:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("context conection=true"))
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
  {
    con.Open();
  }
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ...";
  ...

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cmd.Dispose();
  con.Close();
}
```

I have adding an assembly and the following procedure:

```
Create Proc usp_SaveFinanicalYear
(
  ... params
)
AS
  EXTERNAL NAME SqlLibrary.StoreProcedures.SaveFinanicalYear
```

When I call this procedure I get the following error ([screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go4mc.png)):

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "usp_SaveFinanicalYear":
>   
> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'context conection'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to spell `connection` right. There are two `n`s.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
                               //------------------------^
```

In any case, you shouldn't be using a CLR procedure for a simple `INSERT`. IMHO. This is like hiring a dump truck to get groceries.